# JS изменяет только 1 элемент из 3 document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

Все переменные считаются верно при клике там где надо ***( в соответствующей строке таблицы )***.

Но `document.getElementById` динамически меняется только один из трех..... Голову сломал(

```js
var countSellP1 = 5;
var countSellP2 = 4;
var SummEnd = 0;

function ClickSell(e) {
  switch (e) {
    case 1:
      if (countSellP1 <= 0) {
        alert('!');
        return;
      }
      countSellP1--;
      SummEnd = SummEnd + r1;
      document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = countSellP1;
      document.getElementById('SummEnd').innerHTML = SummEnd.toFixed(2);
      break;

    case 2:
      if (countSellP2 <= 0) {
        alert('!');
        return;
      }
      countSellP2--;
      document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = countSellP2;
      SummEnd = SummEnd + r2;
      document.getElementById('SummEnd').innerHTML = SummEnd.toFixed(2)
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> Количество </th>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="ClickSell(1)">
      <td><span id="p1"> id="p1" </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="ClickSell(2)">
      <td><span id="p2"> id="p2" </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь получить элемент с `id = SummEnd`, которого у вас нет на странице. Необходимо его добавить, чтобы вставлять в него html-код.

И в строчках `SummEnd = SummEnd + r1;` и `SummEnd = SummEnd + r2;` переменные `r1` и `r2` не определены, из-за этого тоже может быть

Comment: <span id="SummEnd" ></span> есть, не указал просто. работает у меня так: отображает/изменяет на странице элемент с  id="p1" и сумэнд. второй p2 ну никак не работает. переменные все считаются корректно, но докГетЭлемент не отправляет на страницу..

Comment: и через отдельные функции на каждый клик делал и через свитч кейс... только один из p1 или p2 выводит ну и SummEnd. :(  countSellP2 считает верно как и countSellP1 и SummEnd (алертами проверял), т.е. в функции видимо все верно... я уж не знаю куда и думать. код в три строки...

Comment: ответ отредактировал, там из-за этого ошибка вылетала и выбивала из свича соответственно)

Comment: спасибо....дело не в том было (код шире чем я привел) но благодаря подсказке пересмотрел более внимательно и похоже скопировав, не изменил имя переменной при обьявлении.. вместо р1 р2 р3 получилось три р1 вначале скрипта, в остальном ничего не увидел, хотя переписал все заново...:))))в общем все работает, как всегда, похоже причина банальная невнимательность.